# Dynamically made Sprite Object has Margin/Padding on Bottom

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Ok, I have no idea why this is happening.

I'm made an Item class which extends the Sprite class, the Item class basically has a few checkmarks & labels at the moment.

Then what I try to do is run through a for loop of items and create Item classes that I want to place one after each other on the y-axis, so I'm reading the Item.height property to find the y of the next Item in the list.

The problem is for some reason there is always an **extra 75 pixels added** to the Sprite height at the bottom, no matter how many checkmarks and labels are in each Item class ( varying the height of the Item class ).

Any idea why this is being added and how it can be removed?

I'm having trouble figuring this out, I tried dynamicly calculating and setting the Item.height property but when I do that the Sprite is simply cropped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes one or two frames until the size of an UI component is correctly set (the default height is 100 pixels).

To prevent this behavior call `validateNow()` on each Flash UI component you add.

```
var s:Sprite = new Sprite();
var label:Label = new Label();
label.text = "hello";
label.x = 0;
s.addChild(label);
var check:CheckBox = new CheckBox();
check.label = "hello";
check.x = 50;
s.addChild(check);
addChild(s);
trace(s.height); // output: 100

label.validateNow();
check.validateNow();
trace(s.height); // output: 28
```

Comment: Thanks, thats the type of thing you gain with experience.